# Fastest method in inverse of matrix

Tags: performance, algorithm, opencv, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I want to process Images with Inverse function and lot of functions. For code to run fastly can any one suggest fast method among the 3 inversion methods ?

```
double cvInvert(const CvArr* src, CvArr* dst, int method=CV_LU)
```

- CV_LU Gaussian elimination with optimal pivot element chosen
- CV_SVD Singular value decomposition (SVD) method
- CV_SVD_SYM SVD method for a symmetric positively-defined matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In OpenCV2.x, there's a new interface called `Mat::inv(int method)` to compute the inverse of a matrix. See [reference](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html).

> C++: MatExpr Mat::inv(int method=DECOMP_LU) const
>
> Parameters:
>          method –
>
> ```
>    Matrix inversion method. Possible values are the following:
>         DECOMP_LU is the LU decomposition. The matrix must be non-singular.
>         DECOMP_CHOLESKY is the Cholesky LL^T decomposition for symmetrical positively defined matrices only. This type is about twice faster than LU on big matrices.
>         DECOMP_SVD is the SVD decomposition. If the matrix is singular or even non-square, the pseudo inversion is computed.
> ```

I made a test with each of the method, it shows that DECOMP_CHOLESKY is the fastest for the test case, and LU gives the similar result.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread("2.png");
    cv::Mat img2, img3, img;
    cv::cvtColor(img1, img2, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    img2.convertTo(img3, CV_32FC1);
    cv::resize(img3, img, cv::Size(200,200));

    double freq = cv::getTickFrequency();

    double t1 = 0.0, t2 = 0.0;
    t1 = (double)cv::getTickCount();
    cv::Mat m4 = img.inv(cv::DECOMP_LU);
    t2 = (cv::getTickCount()-t1)/freq;
    std::cout << "LU:" << t2 << std::endl;

    t1 = (double)cv::getTickCount();
    cv::Mat m5 = img.inv(cv::DECOMP_SVD);
    t2 = (cv::getTickCount()-t1)/freq;
    std::cout << "DECOMP_SVD:" << t2 << std::endl;

    t1 = (double)cv::getTickCount();
    cv::Mat m6 = img.inv(cv::DECOMP_CHOLESKY);
    t2 = (cv::getTickCount()-t1)/freq;
    std::cout << "DECOMP_CHOLESKY:" << t2 << std::endl;

    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

Here  is the running resutls:

> LU:0.000423759
>
> DECOMP_SVD:0.0583525
>
> DECOMP_CHOLESKY:9.3453e-05