# System of linear equation with opencv, c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Can you  explain to me how many and what methods are there in opencv c++ to solve systems of linear equations? if there are already existing tool or function already written, I can list the most efficient?
My system has to solve an equation concerning the processing of digital images

Answer (score 11):

if you have a system `A*x = B` your solution is `x=A^(-1)*B`.
OpenCV allows you to use three different `invert()` method parameter choices:

1. Gaussian elimination with the optimal pivot element chosen.
2. singular value decomposition (SVD) method.
3. Cholesky decomposition; the matrix must be symmetrical and positive-definite.

more information here:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#invert

**edit**:
in addition there is a `solve()` method with additional methods:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#solve

**edit 2**:
there is a short performance comparison for all the three methods:

[Fastest method in inverse of matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040333/fastest-method-in-inverse-of-matrix)

Comment: that might be an error in the openCV documentation, I'll change it in the answer and I'll add some reference about performance.

Comment: If you want to solve `Ax=b`, you should always use `solve()`, and not invert your matrix (for stability, accuracy & performance).