# Simulating matlab's mrdivide with 2 square matrices

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, linear-algebra

I have 2 19x19 square matrices (a & b) and I am trying to use the slash (mrdivide) operator to perform a division such that

```
c = a / b
```

I am trying to implement this in OpenCV.  I've found a few people suggesting using `cv::solve` but so far I've been unable to find anything that gives me a result anything close to matlab.

Does anyone have any idea how I could implement mrdivide with opencv?

I've tried the following code:

```
cv::Mat mldivide(const cv::Mat& A, const cv::Mat& B ) 
{
    //return  b * A.inv();
    cv::Mat a;
    cv::Mat b;
    A.convertTo( a, CV_64FC1 );
    B.convertTo( b, CV_64FC1 );

    cv::Mat ret;
    cv::solve( a, b, ret, cv::DECOMP_NORMAL );

    cv::Mat ret2;
    ret.convertTo( ret2, A.type() );
    return ret2;
}
```

I've then implemented mrdivide as follows:

```
cv::Mat mrdivide(const cv::Mat& A, const cv::Mat& B ) 
{
   return mldivide( A.t(), B.t() ).t();
}
```

(***Edit***: As per the answers this does actually give me the correct answer when I used it correctly!)

This gives me a wrong answer, ie nothing like matlab.  As per the comments I also tried

```
cv::Mat mrdivide(const cv::Mat& A, const cv::Mat& B ) 
{
    return A * B.inv();
}
```

This give the same answer as above but is also wrong.

Comment: a/b = (b'\a')', so try to implement this operation.

Comment: You can also try inverting `b`, then multiplying with `a`.  Did you consider looking at the `cv::invert` function? http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#invert .  Also, there are currently three ways to invert a matrix in OpenCV.  This StackOverflow post goes through the timing of each function for a relatively large matrix size: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040333/fastest-method-in-inverse-of-matrix

Comment: @Goz - That isn't the same as `mrdivide`.  You need to do `A * B.inv()`.  Doing `B.inv()*A` is the same as `B\A` in MATLAB, which is not what you want, right?

Comment: @rayryeng: Sorry thats actually what I meant.  I was trying something and pasted the wrong code.

Comment: @Goz - Ah I see.  Hmm... can you show us a numerical example? How far off is it?

Comment: @rayryeng:  For example the 0,0 is 0.0175 in matlab and -4331.125 using the above code.  They don't even follow similar trends that I can see.

Comment: The input data is actually loaded from a csv written using csvwrite so they should produce, pretty much, identical answers.

Comment: @Goz - I got it... one more question.  Since `c = a / b = a * b^{-1}`... did you check to see if `c*b = a`?

Comment: @rayryeng: Oh dear ... I've made a mistake there.  I still had the code using mldivide with transposes while I was modifying mrdivide (hence getting the same result with both methods ... it wasn't acutally calling it).  Using A * B.inv() I *AM* getting the correct result!

Comment: hahahahahaha, very nice.  I'm glad.  Should I write an answer?

Comment: @rayryeng: please do :)

Comment: @Goz - Ta :) I am now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should NOT be using `inv` to solve `Ax=b` or `xA=b` equations. While the two methods are mathematically equivalent (`x=solve(A,b)` and `x=inv(A)*B`), it's a completely different thing when working with floating-point numbers!
http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/

As a general rule, **never multiply by a matrix inverse**. Instead use the forward/backward-slash operators (or the equivalent "solve" methods) for a one-off system, or explicitly perform matrix factorization (think LU, QR, Cholesky, etc..) when you want to reuse the same `A` with multiple `b`'s

---

Let me give a concrete example to illustrate the problem with inverting. I'll be using MATLAB along with [mexopencv](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/), a library that allows us to call OpenCV directly from MATLAB.

*(this example is borrowed from [this excellent FEX submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24119-don-t-let-that-inv-go-past-your-eyes--to-solve-that-system--factorize-/) by Tim Davis, the same guy behind SuiteSparse. I'm showing the case of left-division `Ax=b` but the same applies for the right-division `xA=b`).*

Let's first build some matrices for the `Ax=b` system:

```matlab
% Ax = b
N = 16;                 % square matrix dimensions
x0 = ones(N,1);         % true solution
A = gallery('frank',N); % matrix with ill-conditioned eigenvalues
b = A*x0;               % Ax=b system
```

Here's what the 16x16 matrix `A` and the 16x1 vector `b` look like (note that the true solution `x0` is just a vector of 1's):

```matlab
A =                                                          b =
   16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1              136
   15 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1              135
    0 14 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1              119
    0  0 13 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1              104
    0  0  0 12 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1               90
    0  0  0  0 11 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1               77
    0  0  0  0  0 10 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1               65
    0  0  0  0  0  0  9  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1               54
    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1               44
    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  7  7  6  5  4  3  2  1               35
    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  6  6  5  4  3  2  1               27
    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  5  5  4  3  2  1               20
    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4  4  3  2  1               14
    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  3  2  1                9
    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  2  1                5
    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1                2
```

Now let's compare [`cv::invert`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#invert) against [`cv::solve`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#solve) by finding the solution and computing the residual error using the NORM function (or [`cv::norm`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#norm) if you want):

```matlab
% inverting (OpenCV)
x1 = cv.invert(A)*b;
r1 = norm(A*x1-b)

% inverting (MATLAB)
x2 = inv(A)*b;
r2 = norm(A*x2-b)

% solve using matrix factorization (OpenCV)
x3 = cv.solve(A,b);
r3 = norm(A*x3-b)

% solve using matrix factorization (MATLAB)
x4 = A\b;
r4 = norm(A*x4-b)
```

Below are the solutions found (I subtract `1` so you can see how far off they are from the true solution `x0`):

```matlab
>> format short g
>> [x1 x2 x3 x4] - 1
ans =
   9.0258e-06   3.1086e-15  -1.1102e-16   2.2204e-16
   -0.0011101  -1.0181e-13  -2.2204e-15  -2.3315e-15
   -0.0016212  -2.5123e-12   3.3751e-14   3.3307e-14
    0.0037279   4.1745e-11  -4.3476e-13  -4.3487e-13
   -0.0022119   4.6216e-10   5.2165e-12    5.216e-12
   -0.0010476   1.3224e-09  -5.7384e-11  -5.7384e-11
    0.0035461   2.2614e-08   5.7384e-10   5.7384e-10
   -0.0040074  -4.1533e-07  -5.1646e-09  -5.1645e-09
    0.0036477   -4.772e-06   4.1316e-08   4.1316e-08
   -0.0033358   4.7499e-06  -2.8922e-07  -2.8921e-07
    0.0059112  -0.00010352   1.7353e-06   1.7353e-06
   -0.0043586   0.00044539  -8.6765e-06  -8.6764e-06
    0.0069238   -0.0024718   3.4706e-05   3.4706e-05
   -0.0019642   -0.0079952  -0.00010412  -0.00010412
    0.0039284      0.01599   0.00020824   0.00020823
   -0.0039284     -0.01599  -0.00020824  -0.00020823
```

And most importantly, here are the errors of each method:

```matlab
r1 =
       0.1064
r2 =
     0.060614
r3 =
   1.4321e-14
r4 =
   1.7764e-15
```

The last two are orders of magnitude more accurate, not even close! And this was just with a system of 16 variables. Inverting is less numerically reliable especially when the matrices are large and sparse...

---

Now to answer your question, you had the right idea of using `cv::solve`, but you just got the order of operands wrong in the case of right-division.

In MATLAB, the operators `/` and `\` (or [`mrdivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html) and [`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html)) are related to each other by the equation `B/A = (A'\B')'` (this is a simple result of [transpose properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#Properties)).

So with OpenCV functions, you would write (note the order of `A` and `b`):

```matlab
% Ax = b
x = cv.solve(A, b);     % A\b or mldivide(A,b)

% xA = b
x = cv.solve(A', b')';  % b/A or mrdivide(b,A)
```

The API exposed by OpenCV is a bit awkward here, so we had to do all these transposes. In fact if you refer to the [equivalent](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/5318/386) LAPACK routines (think `DGESV` or [`DGESVX`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/da/d21/dgesvx_8f.html)) they actually allow you to specify whether the matrix is transposed `TRANS=T` or not `TRANS=N` (at that level, transposition is really just a different memory layout, C or Fortran ordering). MATLAB for instance provides the [`linsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linsolve.html) function which allows you specify these sort of things in the options...

(BTW when coding in C++ OpenCV, I prefer to use the function-form of operations like [`cv::transpose`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#transpose) as opposed to the matrix-expression variants like [`Mat::t`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-t). The former can operate in-place while the latter would create unecessary temporary copies).

Now if you're looking for a good performance linear-algebra implementation in C++, consider using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html) (it even [integrate nicely with OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/daf/group__core__eigen.html)). Plus it's a pure template-based library, so no linking or binaries to worry about, just include the header files.

---

## EDIT (in response to comments)

@Goz:

> look up Return Value Optimisation.
>   The "unnecessary temporary copies" don't exist

I'm aware of [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) and [move semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors), but it's not of much importance here; The `cv::Mat` class is [copy-friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23468537/97160) anyway, kinda like a reference-counted smart pointer. Meaning that it only does a shallow copy with data sharing when passed by-value. The only pieces that get created for the new copy are the parts in the mat header which is insignificant in terms of size (storing stuff like number of dimensions/channels, step sizes, and data type).

I was talking about an explicit deep copy made, not the one you're thinking about when returning from function calls...

Thanks to your comment, it got me motivated to actually dig through the OpenCV sources, which is not the easiest thing to read... Code has little to no comments, and can be hard to follow at times. The complexity is understandable seeing that OpenCV really cares about performance, and it's actually impressive that many functions are implemented in various ways (regular CPU implementation, loop unrolled version, SIMD vectorized versions (SSE, AVX, NEON, etc.), parallel and threaded versions using various backends, optimized implementations from Intel IPP, GPU accelerated versions with OpenCL or CUDA, mobile accelerated versions for Tegra, OpenVX, etc.)

Let's take the following case and trace our steps:

```cpp
Mat A = ..., b = ..., x;
cv::solve(A.t(), b, x);
```

where the function is defined like:

```cpp
bool cv::solve(InputArray _src, InputArray _src2arg, OutputArray _dst, int method)
{
    Mat src = _src.getMat(), _src2 = _src2arg.getMat();
    _dst.create( src.cols, _src2.cols, src.type() );
    Mat dst = _dst.getMat();
    ...
}
```

Now we have to figure out the steps in between. First thing we have is the `t` member method:

```cpp
MatExpr Mat::t() const
{
    MatExpr e;
    MatOp_T::makeExpr(e, *this);
    return e;
}
```

This returns a `MatExpr` which is a class that allows lazy evaluation of [matrix expressions](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions). In other words, it will not perform the transpose right away, instead it stores a reference to the original matrix and the operation to eventually perform on it (transpose), but it will hold off on evaluating it until it is absolutely necessary (for example when assigned or cast to a `cv::Mat`).

Next let's see the definitions of the relevant parts. Note that in the actual code, these things are split across many files. I only pieced the interesting parts here for easier reading, but it's far from the complete thing:

```cpp
class MatExpr
{
public:
    MatExpr()
    : op(0), flags(0), a(Mat()), b(Mat()), c(Mat()), alpha(0), beta(0), s()
    {}
    explicit MatExpr(const Mat& m)
    : op(&g_MatOp_Identity), flags(0), a(m), b(Mat()), c(Mat()),
      alpha(1), beta(0), s(Scalar())
    {}
    MatExpr(const MatOp* _op, int _flags, const Mat& _a = Mat(),
            const Mat& _b = Mat(), const Mat& _c = Mat(),
            double _alpha = 1, double _beta = 1, const Scalar& _s = Scalar())
    : op(_op), flags(_flags), a(_a), b(_b), c(_c), alpha(_alpha), beta(_beta), s(_s)
    {}
    MatExpr t() const
    {
        MatExpr e;
        op->transpose(*this, e);
        return e;
    }
    MatExpr inv(int method) const
    {
        MatExpr e;
        op->invert(*this, method, e);
        return e;
    }
    operator Mat() const
    {
        Mat m;
        op->assign(*this, m);
        return m;
    }
public:
    const MatOp* op;
    int flags;
    Mat a, b, c;
    double alpha, beta;
    Scalar s;
}

Mat& Mat::operator = (const MatExpr& e)
{
    e.op->assign(e, *this);
    return *this;
}
MatExpr operator * (const MatExpr& e1, const MatExpr& e2)
{
    MatExpr en;
    e1.op->matmul(e1, e2, en);
    return en;
}
```

So far this is straightforward. The class is supposed to store the input matrix in `a` (again `cv::Mat` instances will share data, so no copying), along with the operation to perform `op`, and a few other things not important for us.

Here's the matrix operation class `MatOp`, and some of it subclasses (I'm only showing the transpose and inverse operations, but there are more):

```cpp
class MatOp
{
public:
    MatOp();
    virtual ~MatOp();
    virtual void assign(const MatExpr& expr, Mat& m, int type=-1) const = 0;
    virtual void transpose(const MatExpr& expr, MatExpr& res) const
    {
        Mat m;
        expr.op->assign(expr, m);
        MatOp_T::makeExpr(res, m, 1);
    }
    virtual void invert(const MatExpr& expr, int method, MatExpr& res) const
    {
        Mat m;
        expr.op->assign(expr, m);
        MatOp_Invert::makeExpr(res, method, m);
    }
}

class MatOp_T : public MatOp
{
public:
    MatOp_T() {}
    virtual ~MatOp_T() {}
    void assign(const MatExpr& expr, Mat& m, int type=-1) const
    {
        Mat temp, &dst = _type == -1 || _type == e.a.type() ? m : temp;
        cv::transpose(e.a, dst);
        if( dst.data != m.data || e.alpha != 1 ) dst.convertTo(m, _type, e.alpha);
    }
    void transpose(const MatExpr& e, MatExpr& res) const
    {
        if( e.alpha == 1 )
            MatOp_Identity::makeExpr(res, e.a);
        else
            MatOp_AddEx::makeExpr(res, e.a, Mat(), e.alpha, 0);
    }
    static void makeExpr(MatExpr& res, const Mat& a, double alpha=1)
    {
        res = MatExpr(&g_MatOp_T, 0, a, Mat(), Mat(), alpha, 0);
    }
};

class MatOp_Invert : public MatOp
{
public:
    MatOp_Invert() {}
    virtual ~MatOp_Invert() {}
    void assign(const MatExpr& e, Mat& m, int _type=-1) const
    {
        Mat temp, &dst = _type == -1 || _type == e.a.type() ? m : temp;
        cv::invert(e.a, dst, e.flags);
        if( dst.data != m.data ) dst.convertTo(m, _type);
    }
    void matmul(const MatExpr& e1, const MatExpr& e2, MatExpr& res) const
    {
        if( isInv(e1) && isIdentity(e2) )
            MatOp_Solve::makeExpr(res, e1.flags, e1.a, e2.a);
        else if( this == e2.op )
            MatOp::matmul(e1, e2, res);
        else
            e2.op->matmul(e1, e2, res);
    }
    static void makeExpr(MatExpr& res, int method, const Mat& m)
    {
        res = MatExpr(&g_MatOp_Invert, method, m, Mat(), Mat(), 1, 0);
    }
};

static MatOp_Identity g_MatOp_Identity;
static MatOp_T g_MatOp_T;
static MatOp_Invert g_MatOp_Invert;
```

OpenCV is heavily using operator overloading, so all kinds of operations like `A+B`, `A-B`, `A*B`, ... actually map to corresponding matrix expression operations.

The final part of the puzzle is the proxy class `InputArray`. It basically stores a `void*` pointer along with info about the thing passed (what kind it is: `Mat`, `MatExpr`, `Matx`, `vector<T>`, `UMat`, etc..), that way it knows how to cast the pointer back when requested with something like `InputArray::getMat`:

```cpp
typedef const _InputArray& InputArray;

class _InputArray
{
public:
    _InputArray(const MatExpr& expr)
    { init(FIXED_TYPE + FIXED_SIZE + EXPR + ACCESS_READ, &expr); }

    void init(int _flags, const void* _obj)
    { flags = _flags; obj = (void*)_obj; }

    Mat getMat_(int i) const
    {
        int k = kind();
        int accessFlags = flags & ACCESS_MASK;
        ...
        if( k == EXPR ) {
            CV_Assert( i < 0 );
            return (Mat)*((const MatExpr*)obj);
        }
        ...
        return Mat();
    }
protected:
    int flags;
    void* obj;
    Size sz;
}
```

So now we see how `Mat::t` creates and returns a `MatExpr` instance. Which is then received by `cv::solve` as `InputArray`. Now when it calls `InputArray::getMat` to retrieve the matrix, it effectively converts the stored `MatExpr` to a `Mat` calling the cast operator:

```cpp
    MatExpr::operator Mat() const
    {
        Mat m;
        op->assign(*this, m);
        return m;
    }
```

so it declares a new matrix `m`, calls `MatOp_T::assign` with the new matrix as destination. In turn this forces it to evaluate by finally calling `cv::transpose`. It computes the transposed result into this new matrix as destination.

So we end up having two copies, the original `A` and the transposed `A.t()` returned.

Now with all that said, compare it against:

```cpp
Mat A = ..., b = ..., x;
cv::transpose(A, A);
cv::solve(A, b, x);
```

In this case, `A` is transposed *in-place*, and with less levels of abstraction.

---

Now the reason I showed all of that is not to argue about this one extra copy, after all it's not that big of a deal :)
The really neat thing I found out is that the following two expressions are not doing the same thing and give different results (and I'm not talking about whether the inverse is in-place or not):

```cpp
Mat A = ..., b = ..., x;
cv::invert(A,A);
x = A*b;

Mat A = ..., b = ..., x;
x = inv(A)*b;
```

It turns out that the second one is in fact smart enough to call `cv::solve(A,b)`! If you go back to `MatOp_Invert::matmul` (which is called when a lazy invert is later chained with another lazy matrix multiplication).

```cpp
void MatOp_Invert::matmul(const MatExpr& e1, const MatExpr& e2, MatExpr& res) const
{
    if( isInv(e1) && isIdentity(e2) )
        MatOp_Solve::makeExpr(res, e1.flags, e1.a, e2.a);
    ...
}
```

it checks if the first operand in the expression `inv(A)*B` is an invert operation and the second operand is an identity operation (i.e a plain matrix, not the result of another complicated expression). In that case it changes the stored operation to a lazy solve operation `MatOp_Solve` (which similarly is a wrapper for the `cv::solve` function). IMO that's pretty smart! Even though you wrote `inv(A)*b`, it wont actually compute the inverse, and instead it understands that it is better to rewrite it by solving the system using matrix factorization.

Unfortunately for you, this will only benefit expressions of the form `inv(A)*b` not the other way around `b*inv(A)` (that one will end up computing the inverse which is not what we want). So in your case of solving `xA=b`, you should stick with explicitly calling `cv::solve`...

Of course this is only applicable when coding in C++ (thanks to the magic of operator overloading and lazy expressions). If you're using OpenCV from another language using some wrappers (like Python, Java, MATLAB), you're probably not getting any of that, and should be explicit in using `cv::solve` like I did in the previous MATLAB code, for both cases `Ax=b` and `xA=b`.

Hope this helps, and sorry for the long post ;)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Well done Amro.  It's funny because I remember that article by John Cook... and I've even recommended people to reading it... but I went against my better judgment and wanted to try something quick.  It perplexed me how the OP couldn't get it to work.

Comment: btw .. look up Return Value Optimisation.  The "unnecessary temporary copies" don't exist and it makes the code a whole lot easier to follow in my mind.  It also allows for const correctness which can provide far better compiler optimisations than using the C-style interface.

Comment: @Amro: Wow ... I'd give you a second upvote if I could ... care to help me on my mldivide problem in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741319/simulating-matlabs-mldivide-with-opencv ? :D

Answer (score 2):

In MATLAB, using [`mrdivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html)  on two matrices of compatible dimension such that `a / b` is equivalent to `a * b^{-1}` where `b^{-1}` is the inverse of `b`.  As such, what you could do is perhaps invert the matrix `b` first, then pre-multiply this `a`.

One method is to use [`cv::invert`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#invert) on the matrix `b` then pre-multiplying with `a`.  This could be done with the following function definition (borrowing from your code in your post above):

```
cv::Mat mrdivide(const cv::Mat& A, const cv::Mat& B) 
{
    cv::Mat bInvert;
    cv::invert(B, bInvert);
    return A * bInvert;
}
```

Another way is to use the [`inv()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-inv) method that's builtin to the `cv::Mat` interface and just use that and multiply the matrices themselves:

```
cv::Mat mrdivide(const cv::Mat& A, const cv::Mat& B) 
{
    return A * B.inv();
}
```

I'm not sure which one is faster, so you may have to do some tests, but either of the two methods should work.  However, to provide a bit of insight in terms of possible timings, there are three ways to invert a matrix in OpenCV.  You simply override the third parameter to `cv::invert` or specify the method in `cv::Mat.inv()` to facilitate this.

This StackOverflow post goes through the timings of inverting a matrix for a relatively large matrix size using the three methods: [Fastest method in inverse of matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040333/fastest-method-in-inverse-of-matrix)

Comment: no Ray, don't use `inv` to solve a linear system! It is both slower and less accurate. You should instead use a solve method with proper matrix factorization..

Comment: @Amro - You are most certainly right.  Quickest thing I could think of though.